# Displaying django-recurrence in template

Tags: django

I've been banging my head about this for a week or so in my spare time, I currently have in my model

import recurrence.fields
.
.
.
course_recurring  = recurrence.fields.RecurrenceField(null=True)

I can add recurrences and retrieve them in the admin console, but this in the template:  {{ course.course_recurrence.rrules }} returns nothing.

Answer (score 6):

I was suffering from the same problem, but I solved it.
Please try below steps:
1) Include **{{form.media}}** in your html head tag.
2) Please include the following before urlpatterns =[...]
   -**js_info_dict = {'packages': ('recurrence', ),}**
3) Then add this url in the urls.py which includes your template:
   -**url(r'^jsi18n/$', django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog, js_info_dict)**
Note: You need to import django library by including following line in your same urls.py file
   -**import django**

Answer (score 0):

This configuration works well for the new Django:

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.i18n import JavaScriptCatalog


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # ...

    path('jsi18n/', JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(packages=['recurrence']), name='javascript-catalog'),
]

# Connect static files
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**course_form.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'javascript-catalog' %}"> 
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="post" class="post-form">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.media }}
      {{ form }}
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
    </html>
```

**views.py**

```
class CourseCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Course
    fields = ['title', 'price', 'recurrences']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('course-list')
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Course


class CourseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ('title', 'price', 'recurrences', )
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from recurrence.fields import RecurrenceField


class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    recurrences = RecurrenceField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Course'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Courses'
```